# Java String.matches("regex")

Tags: java, regex, string

I don't know regex very well. I am trying to find strings that start with digits 2,3,5 or 7, are 1,3,7 or 9 throughout the middle, and end with 3 or 7.

My attempt was [2357][1379]*[37]. It does not work. I'd appreciate a correction. Remember that this is meant for the Java String.matches() function. Thanks in advance

```
   for (int s = 0; s < primes.size(); ++s) {
        String p = primes.get(s);

        if (!p.matches([REGEX GOES HERE])) {
            System.out.println(p);
            primes.remove(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the regex?

Comment: Your regex works well. The problem lies on somewhere else. (Just in the code you provided.)

Comment: I guess you'd need to use [2357][1379]+[37]. The greedy '+'. If you wish to make sure that there are any of the '1379' digits in the middle of the strong

Comment: By "the code where you create the regex", I mean `p.matches("[2357][1379]*[37]")`.  Java regexes can be annoying to create because of the escape characters.

Comment: Regex looks good. Please post an example of failing match. Also beware leading/trailing whitespace which will cause match to fail.

Comment: Just to make sure - are you looking for 3 digit numbers that fulfill the requirements above ?

Comment: What's the purpose of this regex? Is it to exclude prime numbers? You do know that primes (other than 2 and 5) can end in 1, 3, 7 or 9, right? And they can also have any digit in all positions other than the last one. If you're using this to exclude primes, you'll end up with a ton of false negatives.

Comment: @alfasin 3+ digits. I did fix my problem. It did not have to do with regex. Thanks all

Comment: @NullUserException http://projecteuler.net/problem=37 No, it does an easy filter to find truncatable primes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code "works" just fine:

```
    List<String> primes = new ArrayList<String>();
    primes.add("1");
    primes.add("2");
    primes.add("7");
    primes.add("23");
    primes.add("213");
    primes.add("243");
    primes.add("2113");
    primes.add("2193");
    for (int s = 0; s < primes.size(); ++s) {
        String p = primes.get(s);

        if (!p.matches("[2357][1379]*[37]")) {
            System.out.println(p);
            primes.remove(s);
        }
    }
```

It outputs:

```
1
7
243
```

You may have expected it to output:

```
1
2
7
243
```

However, the `primes.remove(s)` is messing up your loop. That can't really be the intent of your design. (But who knows?!) The following is one of many solutions to avoid messing up your loop:

```
    for (String prime : new ArrayList<String>(primes)) {
        if (!prime.matches("[2357][1379]*[37]")) {
            System.out.println(prime);
            primes.remove(prime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. It wasn't the regex. It was a flaw with the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method of iterating over a collection you remove from in the loop is to iterate **downwards** that way removals don't affect the index of subsequent elements:

```
for (int s = primes.size() - 1; s >= 0; s--) {
    String p = primes.get(s);
    if (!p.matches("[2357][1379]*[37]")) {
        System.out.println(p);
        primes.remove(s);
    }
}
```

No need now to worry about implications of removing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure I am mistaken .. but i dont see anything wrong in your initial pattern for example

```
String aa = "[2357][1379]*[37]";
String bb = "2977313";

boolean matches = Pattern.matches(aa, bb); 
System.out.println("1) "+matches);
```

I started with no 2 and then ended with no 3 and added 1379 in between and it works as expected. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: The number 43, for example, produces matches = false with your test. That is what I want. However, 43 remains in my array in my test, meaning that it thought it matched. It must be a problem with my code

Answer (score 0):

**Your regex works well.** However, `remove` shifts any subsequent elements to the left, so the `String` ordinarily at position `s + 1` is moved to `s`, so the next element to check is at position `s` instead of `s + 1`. Fix:

```
for (int s = 0; s < primes.size();) {
    String p = primes.get(s);

    if (!p.matches("[2357][1379]*[37]")) {
        System.out.println(p);
        primes.remove(s);
    } else 
        ++s;
}
```